# create and sample from a PDF using real data

Tags: r, density-function

I have some highly skewed real world data, from which I want to create a probability density function which I can then use to generate random samples that mimic the original data.  The data is a long list of lengths and it approximates this function in R...

```
library(rBeta2009)
x <- rbeta(10000, 1, 3)
plot(density(x))
```

[image]
How can I obtain parameters from the data which can then be used to create my simulated PDF from which i can sample simulated lengths?

Comment: Why not sample from the data directly?

Comment: Im doing a simulation experiment with over 1000 replications and just feel it would be more statistically sound to sample from a function rather than the raw data

Comment: Are you comfortable making assumptions then about your data generating process? And if yes, can you define them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data has no bounds (and you know that), then one way is the following:

```
d = density(x)
n.new = 1000
x.new <- sample(x, n.new, replace=TRUE) + d$bw*rnorm(n.new, 0, 1)
```

But if you know something more about the data generating process (as @user2974951 's comment asks) such as the pdf is zero at zero or if, in your example above, that there's a lower limit, then the above approach might not be appropriate.

For a lower limit of zero a common practice is to "double the data" but appending the reflection of the data, run density, and then double the resulting y-value.  See

> Silverman, B.W. (1986) Density Estimation for Statistics and Data
> Analysis. Chapman and Hall, London.
> http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4899-3324-9

Here's an implementation related to your example:

```
# Random sample from a beta distribution
  set.seed(12345)
  x <- rbeta(10000, 1, 3)

# Mirror the observations around 0
# (and one could also mirror around 1 if that is appropriate for what you know)
  x.mirrored <- c(x,-x)

# Estimate density for both sets of data
  d <- density(x)
  d.mirrored <- density(x.mirrored)

# Plot the results
  par(mai=c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5))
  plot(d.mirrored$x[d.mirrored$x > 0], 2*d.mirrored$y[d.mirrored$x > 0], 
    xlim=c(0, max(x)), type="l", las=1, lwd=3, ylab="Probability density",
    xlab="X", font.lab=2, cex.lab=2)
  xx <- min(x) + c(0:100)*(max(x) - min(x))/100
  lines(xx, dbeta(xx, 1, 3), col="red", lwd=3)
  lines(d$x[d$x>0], d$y[d$x>0], lwd=3, lty=3)

# Generate new data and find density estimate
  x.new <- abs(sample(x.mirrored, 10000, replace=TRUE) +
    d.mirrored$bw*rnorm(10000, 0, 1))
  d.new <- density(c(x.new, -x.new))
  lines(d.new$x[d.new$x>0], 2*d.new$y[d.new$x>0], col="green", lwd=3)

# Put in legend
  legend(0.4, 2.5, c("True density", "Naive estimate of density",
    "Density estimate using reflection", "Density estimate of new sample"),
    col=c("red", "black", "black", "green"), lty=c(1, 3, 1, 1), lwd=3)
```

[image: True density and various density estimates]